# Measure memory used by a program from another program

Tags: java, memory

Say I have a Java program A from which I call another Java program B, with the help of Process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java B");
```

I also want to calculate the memory used by program B from program A, but am unable to figure it out. I can measure the runtime by the following:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java B");
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long runtime = end - start;
```

I was wondering if we could do something similar, to measure the memory of B from A? I tried doing Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory(), but that will fetch the memory of program A not B.

Comment: You aren't measuring runtime as you don't know that the process has ended: `p.waitFor()`

Comment: Can you provide an answer?

Comment: External tools such as a profiler, VisualVM, the attach API, `ps` and `jmap` may help you find details of memory use of another running Java process.